# How to flash hex files from a micro SD card to an Arduino Nano using an SD card module?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, spi, sd-card, flash

I want to flash a hex file stored in a micro SD card into an Arduino [Uno/Nano]. So far I can read and write to the SD card using Arduino.

Without modifying the bootloader, is it possible to flash the Arduino using micro SD card module?

Comment: Do you have two user accounts? You appear to be suggesting edits from [an account](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/34229/gaurav-sharma) that differs from the account that you originally posted your question from. If you contact the moderators, then they can merge the two accounts for you.

Comment: I have rejected the edit as it changes the focus of the question. What you asked in your edit was a good question - I highly suggest that you [ask](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) it as another question (if it hasn't been asked already).

Answer (score 1):

No. Only the bootloader is allowed to write to the program flash.

Comment: can you show us where this is explained?  The boot loader is just a program and so is the sketch.  I do not see why a sketch can not do what the OP asked.  That said, the knowledge to read the SDCard and modify the non-volatile program memory goes way beyond common Arduino programming knowledge.   One would have to be very familiar the the particular micro processor being used.  Even then it would be a challenge.  To put it another way, this task is easily on par with that of creating the Arduino boot loader in the first place.

Comment: @st2000 the bootloader has this extra privilege that a regular sketch hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I am not sure it can work from the smaller Arduino models. Have a look at the [Phoenard project](http://phoenard.com/). The platform, based on a 2560, flashes .hex files on demand, which are stored on the SD card.

It's an [open-source project](https://github.com/Phoenard/Phoenard), so it should be possible to go through the code and see how they do it.